# Can I use system.io in uwp for external folders when I get access by picker?

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I want to use DirectoryInfo and Fileinfo in uwp for external folders on windows 10.
First, I select folder by picker and get access for StorageFolder.
Next I try to set, for example, LastWriteTime:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(storageFolder.Path); 
directoryInfo.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now;
```

It works for local app folders, but for external folders I recieve error  "Access to the path  -||- is denied". Is it generally possible what I want? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I use system.io in uwp for external folders when I get access by picker?

The short answer is no. `DirectoryInfo` is under system.io namespace, it has no permission to access `DirectoryInfo` with path.

For your requirement, we suggest you use [desktop bridge](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/desktop-bridge-8211-the-bridge-between-desktop-apps-and-the/ba-p/316488) to approach, and edit directoryInfo in desktop extension.

For example

**Wpf extension**

```
System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog openFileDlg = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
var result = openFileDlg.ShowDialog();

if (result.ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(openFileDlg.SelectedPath);
    directoryInfo.LastWriteTime = DateTime.Now;                   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Nico. I can use System.IO to access C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\<packagename>\LocalState and all folder under it.
I understand that the app has the same access rights for folders under LocalState and those picked with Picker. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yep, that correct, you could use Picker to pick the folder to replace accessing with path in UWP platform. But it only available for  folder itself. you can't access the folder with path by using System.IO api.